# Trying to add 3rd tab to tabBarController

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to add a 3rd tab to the tabBarController using ios5.  The standard object you get when you drag it out to your storyboard has 2 tabs.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I searched the internet and all examples start with their tabBarController with the extra tabs without showing how to get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for third tab first add a view controller and then right click the tabview controller and then from it's storyboard segway from relation controll drag to the added view controller and it's done

Comment: Thanks!  I control dragged to the new TVC and it just showed up!

Answer (score 111):

Here is the video I watched that taught me how to add a third tab to a TabBarController:

- [Tab bar for Xcode Swift for iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1_X0DQdY8o)

I will summarize the process below.

## Create a new Tabbed Application project

[image]

This will automatically provide two tabs that already "just work".

[image]

## Add new View Controller

Drag another view controller onto the storyboard.

[image]

## Add Tab Bar Item

Drag a Tab Bar Item onto the new View Controller that you just added.

[image]

## Connect to Tab View Controller

Click and Control-Drag from the Tab View Controller to your new View Controller. A menu will pop up. Choose the **view controllers** option under the **Relationship Segue** group.

[image]

That's it. You should be able to run it now and have all three tabs work. Watch the video that I linked to for more details.

Note:

- To do anything on your new tab, don't forget to add a new View Controller class (as you would for any new View Controller).

Comment: It is almost 2018 and people like me are still searching for how to do it. Sometimes I am baffled by how basic things are not explained properly by official docs or online courses.

Comment: I'm glad this has been such a helpful question.  The thing with this type of development is that it's a very visual type of development, with the dragging from the side, etc.  Back when I asked the question, there weren't any visual answers of how to do anything at all.  I'm glad that @Suragch and others are able to post the pictures of how to do this as well and it's helpful to everyone.

Answer (score 42):

Based on Wolvorin and Tom van responses, and based on what I have experienced you should do as following:

1. Create an empty `View Controller` (in Controllers and Objects)
2. From Windows and Bars, drag `Tab Bar Item` to the newly added view
3. From the main View Controller, select `Tab Bar Controller` icon (next to First Responder), and Control-Drag to the newly added View
4. BOOM you have new tab

Answer (score 17):

To expound on @Roozbeh 's answer, when you control drag from the Tab Bar Controller to the newly added view controller, make sure you select the view controller option under Relationship Seque

[image: Control drag from here]

[image: And select view controllers under Relationship Seque]

I was reading this question after having the same problem and I wanted to clarify what the exact step was.

Comment: this should be top answer, by far the simplest method, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Look in the right part of the screen, I believe it's the Objects library view. Just find the "Tab Item" (or something) and drag it into the bar.

Comment: Thanks for responding to this.  I found out that I could drag from my tab bar controller to my table view controller (or maybe it was the navigation controller) and the 3rd tab just "magically" appears.